# How to find what causes my notebook to crash?

Tags: ubuntu, nvidia, crash, acpi, nouveau

I have a new notebook and it crashes frequently.

```
$ uname -a
Linux bpgergo-notebook 4.2.0-27-generic #32-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 22 04:49:08 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.10
Release:    15.10
Codename:   wily
```

I cannot specify any circumstance or application that is specific to the crash. I would like to find out the cause of the crash. I will describe how it looks like when it crashes and what I can see in the syslog. I would like you to tell me how to proceed with finding the cause.

### How it looks when it crashes

Sometimes it would freeze within one our of a restart, some other time within 2 days. E.g. when this latest freeze happened, after restart I just started some ordinary applications like a browser and a terminal, left it alone for an hour and when I got back to it, I noticed that it did not respond to anything. Not even to alt+ctl+F1. The only thing I can do at this point is to keep the power button pressed until it turns off.

When the freeze happens, I usually notice, that the notebook is a bit warmer then it should be. If I immediately restart and check `sensors` then I can see temperatures like 70 degrees Celsius which is not extreme but much higher then normal operation temp which is around 50.

### syslogs

I have checked the /var/log/syslog, this is what I found to be the latest log lines before it crashed.
chrash1:

```
Feb 10 15:01:39 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [26093.242080] nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] HUB0: 0x6013d4 0xffff5703 (0x1c408200)
Feb 10 15:01:39 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [26093.242132] nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] HUB0: 0x10ecc0 0xffffffff (0x1a40822c)
Feb 10 15:02:09 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [26123.130129] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150619/nsarguments-95)
Feb 10 15:02:09 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [26123.130403] ACPI: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP: failed to evaluate _DSM
Feb 10 15:02:09 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [26123.130407] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150619/nsarguments-95)
Feb 10 15:02:11 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [26124.445525] nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] HUB0: 0x10ecc0 0xffffffff (0x1c40822c)
```

crash 2

```
Feb 10 16:17:58 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [ 1088.808587] nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] HUB0: 0x6013d4 0xffff5700 (0x1c408200)
Feb 10 16:18:23 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [ 1113.486503] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150619/nsarguments-95)
Feb 10 16:18:23 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [ 1113.487291] ACPI: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP: failed to evaluate _DSM
Feb 10 16:18:23 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [ 1113.487305] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150619/nsarguments-95)
Feb 10 16:18:26 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [ 1116.831356] nouveau E[    PBUS][0000:01:00.0] MMIO read of 0x00000000 FAULT at 0x122130 [ IBUS ]
Feb 10 16:18:26 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [ 1116.835021] nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] HUB0: 0xbad00100 0xbadf1002 (0xbad00100)
Feb 10 16:18:26 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [ 1116.835247] nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] ROP4: 0xbadf1100 0xbadf1100 (0xbadf1100)
Feb 10 16:18:26 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [ 1116.835252] nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] ROP6: 0xbadf1100 0xbadf1100 (0xbadf1100)
Feb 10 16:18:26 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [ 1116.835257] nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] ROP7: 0xbadf1100 0xbadf1100 (0xbadf1100)
Feb 10 16:18:26 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [ 1116.835262] nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] ROP9: 0xbadf1100 0xbadf1100 (0xbadf1100)
Feb 10 16:18:26 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [ 1116.835267] nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] ROP11: 0xbadf1100 0xbadf1100 (0xbadf1100)
Feb 10 16:18:26 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [ 1116.835271] nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] ROP12: 0xbadf1100 0xbadf1100 (0xbadf1100)
Feb 10 16:18:26 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [ 1116.835276] nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] ROP13: 0xbadf1100 0xbadf1100 (0xbadf1100)
Feb 10 16:18:26 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [ 1116.835281] nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] ROP15: 0xbadf1100 0xbadf1100 (0xbadf1100)
Feb 10 16:18:26 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [ 1116.835286] nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] GPC8: 0xbadf1100 0xbadf1100 (0xbadf1100)
Feb 10 16:18:26 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [ 1116.835293] nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] GPC20: 0x000000 0x00000000 (0x00000000)
Feb 10 16:18:26 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [ 1116.835298] nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] GPC22: 0xbadf1100 0xbadf1100 (0xbadf1100)
Feb 10 16:18:26 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [ 1116.835303] nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] GPC23: 0xbadf1100 0xbadf1100 (0xbadf1100)
Feb 10 16:18:26 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [ 1116.835308] nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] GPC25: 0xbadf1100 0xbadf1100 (0xbadf1100)
Feb 10 16:18:26 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [ 1116.835312] nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] GPC27: 0xbadf1100 0xbadf1100 (0xbadf1100)
Feb 10 16:18:26 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [ 1116.854481] nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] GPC28: 0xbad00100 0xbad00100 (0xbad00100)
Feb 10 16:18:26 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [ 1116.877204] nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] GPC29: 0xbad00100 0xbad00100 (0xbad00100)
Feb 10 16:18:26 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [ 1116.900634] nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] GPC31: 0xbad00100 0xbad00100 (0xbad00100)
Feb 10 16:18:26 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [ 1116.992570] nouveau E[    PBUS][0000:01:00.0] MMIO read of 0x00000000 FAULT at 0x120058 [ IBUS TIMEOUT ]
Feb 10 16:18:26 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [ 1117.072344] nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] HUB0: 0xbad00100 0xbad00100 (0xbad00100)
Feb 10 16:18:26 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [ 1117.078887] nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] ROP4: 0xbad00100 0xbadf1100 (0xbadf1100)
Feb 10 16:18:26 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [ 1117.078904] nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] ROP6: 0xbadf1100 0xbadf1100 (0xbadf1100)
Feb 10 16:18:26 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [ 1117.078910] nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] ROP7: 0xbadf1100 0xbadf1100 (0xbadf1100)
Feb 10 16:18:26 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [ 1117.078917] nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] ROP9: 0xbadf1100 0xbadf1100 (0xbadf1100)
Feb 10 16:18:26 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [ 1117.078923] nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] ROP11: 0xbadf1100 0xbadf1100 (0xbadf1100)
Feb 10 16:18:26 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [ 1117.078939] nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] ROP12: 0xbadf1100 0xbadf1100 (0xbadf1100)
Feb 10 16:18:26 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [ 1117.078945] nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] ROP13: 0xbadf1100 0xbadf1100 (0xbadf1100)
Feb 10 16:18:26 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [ 1117.078950] nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] ROP15: 0xbadf1100 0xbadf1100 (0xbadf1100)
Feb 10 16:18:26 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [ 1117.078954] nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] GPC8: 0xbadf1100 0xbadf1100 (0xbadf1100)
Feb 10 16:18:26 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [ 1117.078960] nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] GPC20: 0x000000 0x00000000 (0x00000000)
Feb 10 16:18:26 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [ 1117.078964] nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] GPC22: 0xbadf1100 0xbadf1100 (0xbadf1100)
Feb 10 16:18:26 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [ 1117.078968] nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] GPC23: 0xbadf1100 0xbadf1100 (0xbadf1100)
Feb 10 16:18:26 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [ 1117.078971] nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] GPC25: 0xbadf1100 0xbadf1100 (0xbadf1100)
Feb 10 16:18:26 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [ 1117.078975] nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] GPC27: 0xbadf1100 0xbadf1100 (0xbadf1100)
Feb 10 16:18:26 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [ 1117.078978] nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] GPC28: 0xbadf1100 0xbadf1100 (0xbadf1100)
Feb 10 16:18:26 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [ 1117.078982] nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] GPC29: 0xbadf1100 0xbadf1100 (0xbadf1100)
Feb 10 16:18:26 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [ 1117.078987] nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] GPC31: 0x000000 0x00000000 (0x00000000)
Feb 10 16:18:26 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [ 1117.078997] nouveau E[    PBUS][0000:01:00.0] MMIO read of 0x00000000 FAULT at 0x120058 [ IBUS TIMEOUT ]
Feb 10 16:18:26 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [ 1117.079008] nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] HUB0: 0x136928 0xbadf1100 (0x19400200)
Feb 10 16:18:26 bpgergo-notebook kernel: [ 1117.079014] nouveau E[   PIBUS][0000:01:00.0] ROP0: 0x10f904 0xffffffff (0x1e408201)
```

Comment: I know this is going to sound like dumb advice, but have you tried to boot it in to recovery mode (a.k.a. safe mode) Does it exhibit the same behavior when in recovery mode ? Most inexplicable crashes I have lived through, can be attributed to a misbehaving driver, usually graphics card driver more than anything else.

Comment: well, nouveau is the graphics driver for nvidia cards, which I happen to have. So I am in the process of installing the official driver, see if that helps.

Comment: have a look https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-nouveau/+bug/1378881

Answer (score 0):

So to answer my question,

1. find out what is the program or package that is writing the last lines in the syslog before the crash
2. this a directory should be also checked: `/var/crash/`

As commenters pointed it out, nouveau is the open source nvidia driver.

Regarding the concrete problem, I had installed proprietary nvidia driver, since then I haven't had any more crash.